# How to filter JSON in java

Tags: java, json, filter

I have a JSON like below:

```js
{
    "name": "John",
    "age": 29,

    "city": "Bangalore",
    "country": "India"
}
```

But based on the request, I need to filter only the name and city. My response should be like the following:

```js
{    
    "name": "John",
    "city": "Bangalore"
}
```

How do we achieve this using Java code?

Comment: Which json library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All JSON libraries with query capability can do that, such as *Josson*.

https://github.com/octomix/josson

```
Josson josson = Josson.fromJsonString(
    "{" +
    "    \"name\": \"John\"," +
    "    \"age\": 29," +
    "    \"city\": \"Bangalore\"," +
    "    \"country\": \"India\"" +
    "}");
JsonNode node = josson.getNode("map(name, city)");
System.out.println(node.toPrettyString());
```

**Output**

```
{
  "name" : "John",
  "city" : "Bangalore"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 3 ways to do it, which are library agnostic:

1. Deserialize the data into a class (let's say `Request`) -> transform that into the `Response` object -> serialize the response

```
public class Request {

  private String name;
  private int age;
  private String city;
  private String country;
}
```

```
public class Response {

  private String name;
  private String city;
}
```

2. Use one class (see `Request` example above, but with more appropriate name) with custom serializer/deserializer. The deserializer will read all properties, the serializer will write only the ones you need - `name` and `city`.
3. Use the generic object - `Map<String, Object>`. Deserialize into a `Map` -> remove properties you don't need from it (`age`, `country`) -> serialize the map.

There are more ways, which are specific to the json library used, but generally they will follow the same approach - read input -> either take only what you need or remove only what you don't need -> write output.